# How to determine the winner

Tags: probability

One box contains $3$ white and $4$ black cards. Person $A$ and $B$ (first person $A$ then person $B$) consecutively draw letters without return. The winner is the one who will draw the black card. Find:

$a)$ The X-winner is player B

$b)$ Y-number of draws, and the values ​​shown graphically

My attemp: Part $a)$ $$X=B_2\cup B_2^cA_1^cB_4$$
$$P(X)=P(B_2)+ P(B_2)P(A_1^c|B_2^c)P(B_4|B_2A_1^c)$$
$$P(X)=\frac{4}{7}+\frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{6}\frac{4}{5}=0.8$$

Did I work well part $a).$

For the part $b)$ i started:

$P(Y=1)=P(B_2)=\frac{4}{7}$

$P(Y=2)=P(B_2^cA_1)=P(B_2^c)P(A_1|B_2^c)=\frac{3}{7}\frac{3}{6}=0.214$

I don't know if I started well, and how far it has to go. Thanks for your attetnion and your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem as it is stated. Here is my best attempt at understanding it.

Let $W,B$ represent a draw of a white card or a black card respectively. We will write out sequences of draws where odd positions are drawn by player A and even positions by player B. The following sequences yield player B as a winner:

$$WB,WWWB$$

So, the probabilities of those draws are:
$$P(B_2) = P(A_1^C)\cdot P(B_2|A_1^C) = \dfrac{3}{7}\cdot \dfrac{4}{6} = \dfrac{2}{7}$$

and

$$P(B_4) = P(A_1^C)P(B_2^C|A_1^C)P(A_3^C|(A_1^C\cap B_2^C))P(B_4|(A_1^C\cap B_2^C\cap A_3^C)) = \dfrac{3}{7}\cdot \dfrac{2}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{5}\cdot \dfrac{4}{4} = \dfrac{1}{35}$$

So, the total $P(X) = P(B_2)+P(B_4) = \dfrac{2}{7}+\dfrac{1}{35} = \dfrac{11}{35}$.

For part (b), it no longer seems to indicate that player B is the winner (please correct me if I am wrong). Additionally, it appears that you are looking for the expected value of the number of draws (again, please correct me if I am wrong). So, you can have 1, 2, 3, or 4 draws before finding a winner. The expected value is found by taking the sum of the products of the number of draws and the probability of achieving that number of draws.

$$\begin{align*}E[\text{number of draws}] & = 1\cdot P(A_1) + 2\cdot P(B_2) + 3\cdot P(A_3) + 4\cdot P(B_4) \\ & = P(A_1) + 2P(A_1^C)P(B_2|A_1^C) + 3P(A_1^C)P(B_2^C|A_1^C)P(A_3|(A_1^C\cap B_2^C)) + 4P(A_1^C)P(B_2^C|A_1^C)P(A_3^C|(A_1^C\cap B_2^C))P(A_4|(A_1^C\cap B_2^C\cap A_3^C)) \\ & = \dfrac{4}{7}\cdot 1 + \dfrac{3}{7}\cdot \dfrac{4}{6}\cdot 2 + \dfrac{3}{7}\cdot \dfrac{2}{6}\cdot \dfrac{4}{5}\cdot 3 + \dfrac{3}{7}\cdot \dfrac{2}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{5}\cdot \dfrac{4}{4}\cdot 4 = \dfrac{8}{5}\end{align*}$$

Comment: can you tell me how you got the numbers $\frac{3}{7},$ $\frac{2}{6}$ ects

Comment: Player A has to draw first. There are 7 cards to start and player A must draw a white card. There is a $\dfrac{3}{7}$ chance of that. Next, player B must draw a black card. There are now 4 black cards and 2 white cards, so the probability of drawing a black card is $\dfrac{4}{6}$. Etc.

Comment: can you please write them down a bit ie $P(B_2^c|A_1)$ to understand it better. Please

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer. I am not sure how this will aid with your understanding. It looks far more confusing than before.